# Entity Framework Core Migration tool issue Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have been getting following errors, while generating database migration :-

Command Prompt:-

```
C:Shop\eWebShop\Web>dotnet ef migrations add "InitialDatabase" --context WebContext -p ../Persistence/Persistence.csproj -o Data/Migrations
```

Error:-

```
Unable to create an object of type 'WebContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Tried through Package Manager Console:-

Command:-

```
Add-Migration InitialDatabase -Context WebContext -p Persistence -o Data/Migrations
```

Error:-

```
Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Migration InitialDatabase -Context WebContext -p Persistence -o D ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: what version of the .net core are you using?

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes  if you are using .NET Core 3

You might need to run the install command from PMC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are missing some Package References , Make sure you had all of them in .csproj file

`<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19307.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview6-19319-03" />
  </ItemGroup>`